# what is wrong with my code? leetcode - 189. Rotate Array

Tags: python-3.x

The code works perfectly fine for the first test case but gives wrong answer for the second one. Why is that?

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
arr2 = [-1,-100,3,99]

def reverse(array, start, end):
    while start < end:
        array[start], array[end] = array[end], array[start]
        start += 1
        end -= 1
    return array

def rotate(array, k):
    reverse(array, 0, k)
    reverse(array, k+1, len(array)-1)
    reverse(array, 0, len(array)-1)
    return array


print(rotate(arr, 3))       # output: [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# print(reverse(arr, 2, 4))
rotate(arr2, 2)
print(arr2)                 # output: [99, -1, -100, 3] (should be [3, 99, -1, -100])
```

Comment: I guess that the even number of elements in `arr2` and negative indexing are to be blamed.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing logic does the following -

1. Move `k + 1` item from front of the list to the back of the list.

But the solution needs to move `k` elements from back of the list to the front. Or another way to think is move `len(array) - k` element from front to the back.

To do so, two changes required in the `rotate()` -

1. Update `k` to `len(array) - k`
2. Change your logic to move `k` instead of `k + 1` element from front to back

So, your `rotate()` needs to be changed to following -

```
def rotate(array, k):
    k = len(array) - k
    reverse(array, 0, k-1)
    reverse(array, k, len(array)-1)
    reverse(array, 0, len(array)-1)
    return array
```

I think there are better ways to solve this but with your logic this should solve the problem.

Comment: but as per leetcode's example 1, it should be [5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4] and not ]4,5,6,7,1,2,3]

Comment: @VRM, can you check now?

Comment: i'm getting wrong answers for both now

Comment: sorry my bad. didn't update k to k -1. gives correct outputs but can you please explain the logic behind it?

Comment: @VRM, updated my answer. Have a look